# change font on click

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-family

I want change font after click button
Its my code :

```
<div id="page">Hello world</div>
<div id="font-load"></div>
<a id="iransans">click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#iransans").click(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#font-load').load("class/client_setting.php?font=iransans", function(){});
            $("#page").addClass("iransans-font");
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .iransans-font{
        font-family: iransans !important;
    }
</style>
```

It isn't work for me.
I want change font after click and add class

Comment: Swap `$("#iransans").click` and `$(document).ready`.

Comment: I tested it isn't work

Comment: I had a little play here http://jsbin.com/ripewasode/edit?html,js,output

Comment: what does `class/client_setting.php?font=iransans` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iransans").click(function(){
         //$("#page").css("font-family", 'Arial'); //to change the font directly
         $("#page").addClass("iransans-font"); //to add the class on click
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.iransans-font{
    font-family: Arial !important; //change your font here..
}
</style> 

<div id="page">Hello world</div>
<div id="font-load"></div>
<a id="iransans">click me</a>
```

Comment: OP is trying to load in a third-party font.

Comment: @evolutionxbox updated the answer assuming his css class is working fine..